# Is there a way to set a breakpoint for word wrapping?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that displays a name, date, and time in the following format:

```
By John Doe on: mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM AM
```

The area I'm displaying this in is fixed width, and if the username is too long it can cut the time off like so:

```
By John Doe on: mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM
AM
```

When I would prefer the time to wrap with the AM/PM

```
By John Doe on: mm/dd/yyyy
HH:MM AM
```

Is there a way to set a breakpoint, or similar concept, that tells the page it can break between the date and time, but not to break between the time and AM/PM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrapping each element in a span and disallowing breakage

```css
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

div {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>By John Doe on:</span>
  <span>mm/dd/yyyy</span>
  <span>HH:MM AM</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, what you need is the ***real*** purpose of non-breaking space ***&nbsp;***

So just try: HH:MM&nbsp;AM/PM